# Increase quotas at google cloud vm

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, quota

Recently I am trying to get benefits of google cloud accelerators by adding gpus to ma my vm therefore, an increase for quotas was requested so I sent an request for 8 gpus and I got the below email

Note I tried multibele times

[image]

So could any one explain what exactly happen and how could get the increase successfully ... Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue related only to your GCP quotas and unfortunately Stack Overflow community can do nothing with such issues.

Have a look at the email from Google Cloud Support again:

> Unfortunately, we are unable to grant you additional quota at this
>   time. If this is a new project please wait 48h until you resubmit the
>   request or until your Billing account has additional history.
>
> Your Sales Rep is a good Escalation Path for these requests, and we
>   highly recommend you to reach out to them.
>
> If you have any further questions, please reply to this thread or feel
>   free to reach out to us at gc-team@google.com.

**To solve this issue** you can try steps below:

- Try to work for a while with current quotas, if it possible for your use case, to get some history on your account and after that [request an increase in quota](https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas#requesting_additional_quota).
- Try to split desired increase in quota into some steps that could be approved like 1 -> 2 -> 4 -> 8.
- Try to reach [Google Sales Team](https://cloud.google.com/contact).
- Try to reply again to `gc-team@google.com` but provide some arguments to clarify your request.

Comment: Thanks a lot for replaying so you were saying that this is normal and somehow it depends on how much I have worked with the my vm please note the this is the first time I am working with gcp because I am in harry and need the accelerators to work as soon as possible anyway thank you I will try those steps.

Comment: You should work for a while and try to ask for quota increase in a few steps, because you've just started. I've seen a few similar cases to yours before with the same issue.

Comment: Have the same problem, I want to increase the limit of the number of GPUs from 0 to 1. But get the same email. Also, I have an account for more than 48 hours created. And I was paying paid for other services. This is not a clear situation and I can not see clear approaches to how to deal with it.

Comment: It's better to contact Google back and ask for their reasons and provide yours in such a case.