# Increase quotas at google cloud platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Recently I am working with google cloud platform in order to training a machine learning model 
Unfortunatly I was trying to increase quotas in order to get benefit of GPUs but the request has been rejected on behave That I need to get more billing history 
Therefore my question is there any steps I could do to accelerate the process.
In other hand If I would work with other platform like amazon or azure would the process of using GPUs going to be easier.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming

Answer (score 3):

It happens to some fresh projects and unfortunately Stack Overflow community can do nothing with such issues.

Have a look again at the email from Google Cloud Support, I think it looks similar to this:

> Unfortunately, we are unable to grant you additional quota at this
>   time. If this is a new project please wait 48h until you resubmit the
>   request or until your Billing account has additional history.
>
> Your Sales Rep is a good Escalation Path for these requests, and we
>   highly recommend you to reach out to them.
>
> If you have any further questions, please reply to this thread or feel
>   free to reach out to us at gc-team@google.com.

**To solve this issue** you can try steps below:

- Try to work for a while with current quotas, if it possible for your use case, to get some history on your account and after that [request an increase in quota](https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas#requesting_additional_quota).
- Try to split desired increase in quota into some steps that could be approved like 1 -> 2 -> 4 -> 8.
- Try to reach [Google Sales Team](https://cloud.google.com/contact).
- Try to reply again to gc-team@google.com but provide some arguments to clarify your request.

In addition, please have a look at the few similar cases [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/1014917) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61888413).

Comment: Thanks dear I just wonder if I want to work with amazon or microsoft azure could this process takes less time because I need to get gpus as soon as possible ...thanks in advance

Comment: Try to contact with Google Sales Team first. I think they're able to help you.

Comment: @kikicoder - You are dealing with a credit situation. Is your credit good enough to justify a cloud vendor allowing access to resources that you pay for later? In my experience with AWS, Azure, and GCP, Google has tended to be easier/more relaxed. Review the credit card that you posted to your billing account. Does it only have $12.00 in credit available or are you using a corporate debit card? Are you a hobbyist or a business? How long has your account been open? These are factors that companies might consider in granting a credit line increase. Only the vendor can increase your credit line.