# Availability of V100 and P100 on Google Compute Engine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine

### Description

I just tried for some time to set up or reserve a virtual machine for machine learning with my personal account that I'm using for some months on n1 with around 8 or more GB Ram and either a P100 or a V100 for machine learning and now tried for at least half of all zones with P100/V100 availability and always get a Resource Error like this one:

> Operation type [insert] failed with message "The zone 'projects/lexical-list-285719/zones/us-central1-c' does not have enough resources available to fulfill the request. Try a different zone, or try again later."

no resources available in zone-x. I recently switched from the trial.

### Questions:

A) Is that common?

B) Is there a fix?

C) What (if anything) can I do to get a machine with these specifications, or similar performance?

I know that this is because of the zone not having these specifications available and that I'm supposed to try switching. I'm aware too of managed instance groups. But it can't be that difficult, can it?

Is google that booked out?

### Possible Solutions

Currently my ideas to fix it:

- multizone managed group (still have to check if my project is compatible with that)
- cloud shell script that iterates through all available zones (would need to research how shell scripts works)

Anyone with experience in this topic sharing their experience with the solutions or with better solutions is very appreciated.

⁣

⁣

A good answer for me would **not** include any of the following:

- Zone Switching (tried that)
- Smaller machine (tried that and project doesn't work with too small machine)
- Reserving (tried that)
- Waiting (already know about that and doesn't help if I want a machine right now)

Though I recommend anyone with less persistent or urgent issues to do just those.

Comment: Could you please provide exact error message? Do you have available quota for P100/V100 in zones where you've tried to request them? If not, have you tried to request an increase in quota?

Comment: For how long do you have your GCP account? Do you use a personal one?

Comment: First time failed due to quota, I requested and got confirmed quota. @SerhiiRohoza

For some months and yes

Thanks for helping me

Comment: I am able to create GPU VMs without issue, I only receive this error when trying to to create V100 GPU VMs, so I guess there are no V100s available.... Tried again after 12 hours but still nothing.

Answer (score 2):

*It's not an issue*, events like this happens from time to time.

This error message means that *there's no available resources like CPU/RAM/GPU on the Google's side in the particular zone*. More details the you can find at the documentation [Troubleshooting VM creation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-instances#vm-not-created) section [Resource availability](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-vm-creation#resource_availability):

> Resource errors occur when you try to request new resources in a zone
> that cannot accommodate your request due to the current unavailability
> of a Compute Engine resource, such as GPUs or CPUs.
>
> Resource errors only apply to new resource requests in the zone and do
> not affect existing resources. Resource errors are not related to your
> Compute Engine quota and only apply to the resource you specified in
> your request at the time you sent the request, not to all resources in
> the zone.

Resource availability are depending from users requests and therefore are dynamic.

**There are a few ways to solve this issue**:

1. Try to create your instance at another [zone where GPU is available](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus/gpu-regions-zones) ([request an increase in quota](https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas#requesting_additional_quota) if needed).
2. Wait for a while and try again.
3. Request some smaller VM (if possible), later you'll be able to try to request some bigger VM (same principle as for [quota requests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62128974/12428794)).
4. [Reserve resources](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/reserving-zonal-resources) for your VM by following documentation to avoid such issue in future (*extra payment required*).

Comment: This is a good answer for someone who just started encountering this problem. I had tried all of that except 2 already, after reading other answers.

So I assume, A) yes this is common,
B) no (because for me the solutions failed too, so for me in that moment, there is no fix(and you can't reasonably expect a costumer to try all of the hundreds of different gpu/cpu/ram/zone combinations there are)
C) You can't/just pray the compute gods show mercy when you try the next time.

It looks like to me that a managed group or a script that test for availability are possible solutions.

Comment: I appreciate it but it doesn't really solve my problems.

Comment: Sorry to hear that, but in this case community can only describe current situation to make it more clear and suggest some workarounds. Unfortunately, community can do nothing to solve resource availability issues on the GCP side. You can try reach out to Google Cloud Support and/or Google Cloud Sales.

Comment: Going back yo your questions: A) It happens from time to time and it depends on current demand (if you don't use resource reservation). B) No, but some workarounds are available (at the docs and in my answer).  C) You can try some configurations, but there's no 100% working solution. *Managed Instance Group* will use a few VMs instead of 1 powerful VM, but same zonal CPU/RAM/GPU, as a result, it *depends on zonal resource availability* in the same way as a single VM.

Comment: Groups: True but less of a pain in the .... because as far as I'm aware it will switch to a different machine if there is no zonal availability. I'm aware of limited resource, no doubt they exist, but I'm questioning if I have to brute force zones and configurations to find out which configuration works. It seems a little strange that google does not check that in the web interface. Also reservation failed for me (same Error message) just like directly creating

Comment: And if it really is stupid like that, to let my frustration out over the more than one hour of trying to find a configuration that fits, that's okay too. As a beginner I was just wondering if I'm doing something wrong. More than an hour to set up a machine seemed strange to me.

Comment: If there isn't V100s or the GPU requested available, why would it be listed as an option @SerhiiRohoza ?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, I was trying to create V100s, I was able to get it working by switching zones to `europe-west4`.

What I tried if you're curious: All the sub zones in us-central1 (failed), One sub zone in us-west1 (failed), finally europe-west4 (Success).

This tells me it's due to the zones not having the GPU available. I really wish google wouldn't list it as an option since it doesn't actually have the ability to provision it. Or provide another way of knowing.