# Google compute - Machine types supporting V100 GPU

Tags: google-compute-engine

I am trying to find a machine type which allows me to select a V100 GPU in the Singapore region. I can't find this in the documentation and I can't seem to select it in the machine types in the pricing calculator. I can only select a T4 and P4 with the N1 machine type, or the A100 using the A2 machine type. Besides clicking on every instance of every machine and checking if GPU is even available (largely not so far) is the machine -> GPU availability listed in the doco somewhere?

Many thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Availability of V100 and P100 on Google Compute Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67647184/availability-of-v100-and-p100-on-google-compute-engine)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, **NVIDIA Tesla V100** GPU type is not supporting some of the regions and in that Asia-Southeast1 (Singapore) is included. If you want to choose the Singapore region, you can select **A100, P4, T4** GPU machine types. To select the V100 GPU, you need to select different zones that are included in the [documentation.](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus/gpu-regions-zones?_ga=2.129578700.-1737682304.1633423581#gpu_regions_and_zones)

Try to create your instance at another zone where GPU is available ([request an increase in quota if needed](https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas#requesting_additional_quota)).

Refer to the image which shows that you cannot select V100 for the Singapore region.

[image]