# Should I wait for 2 days until be able to use GPU in GCP even after Upgrade

Tags: google-cloud-platform, quota

I know the limitation of using GPU in GCP that's mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65843064/how-to-request-for-gpu-quota-increase-for-nvidia-a100-for-ai-platform-noteboo).
I have upgraded my account.

I submitted a request to increase the quota but I got this response:

> Unfortunately, we are unable to grant you additional quota at this
> time. If this is a new project please wait 48h until you resubmit the
> request or until your Billing account has additional history

Should I wait for 2 days as they mentioned or there's a wrong configuration from my side?

Comment: Your question lacks details such as the region you are requesting the quota increase. Your project might already have GPU available in one region such as us-central1 but not in other regions. GPUs are expensive and a quota increase means a credit line increase. Make sure your credit card is valid, sufficient credit is available, addresses match, you are using real email addresses, etc.

Answer (score 1):

*Yes, you should wait at least 48 hours*. It happens to some fresh projects and unfortunately Stack Overflow community can do nothing with such issues.

**To solve this issue** you can try steps below:

- Try to work for a while with current quotas, if it possible for your use case, to get some history on your account and after that [request an increase in quota](https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas#requesting_additional_quota).
- If your request rejected after 48 hours, try to split it in a few smaller requests.
- Send your justifications to gc-team@google.com or/and contact [Google Sales Team](https://cloud.google.com/contact).

In addition, please have a look at the few similar cases [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/1014917) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61888413).